# Hash url (fragment) can be crawlable by search engines?

Tags: php, angularjs, .htaccess, url, hash

I've been working on angularjs and php.

I have this url sample:

> www.example.com/#/mysite

I'm trying to search it to google and I cant find it and why?

Is there a way if I search `"mysite www.example.com"` and it will show the results in search engines (google.com) would be `"www.example.com/mysite"` and once I click the link it will be redirected to `www.example.com/#/mysite`.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [HTML5 mode of the location provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#hashbang-and-html5-modes) in AngularJS. Google won't index URLs which are routed behind a hash. This should work both for Angular standard Router and ui-router. Read the whole article about HTML5 mode, since there is a lot to be careful about (including Google crawling).

Enable it by adding `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` to the `config()` section of your app module.

The main caveat is that copy-pasting a URL will not work and you have to configure server side that all the paths render the Angular App. ui-router has some good [documentation about this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode)